# What date does 'Ender's Game' take place?

Tags: setting, enders-game, orson-scott-card

Does the book ever specify the date of when the story takes place?

Comment: [Same question on another SE site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45786/31394) (although it doesn't have a fully satisfactory/canonical answer yet). Also [this Wiki link](http://enderverse.wikia.com/wiki/Enderverse_Timeline) may have some good info.